# Updating tlmgr on macOS Big Sur

Tags: texlive, mactex, tlmgr, macos

I installed macOS Big Sur (11.1) on my MacBook Pro as well as [BasicTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) and I am trying to update `tlmgr` by running `sudo tlmgr update --self` but an error occurs. I guess the main message is that `only MacOSX is supported, not darwin 11.1` but the complete output that I get is as follows.

```
/Library/TeX/texbin/tlmgr: only MacOSX is supported, not darwin 11.1  (from sw_vers -productVersion: 11.1)
query_ctan_mirror: Programs not set up, trying wget
cannot contact mirror.ctan.org, returning a backbone server!
tlmgr: package repository http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2020basic/tlpkg/backups
TLPDB::_install_package: unsupported container format xz
tlmgr: Installation of new version of texlive.infra failed, trying to unwind.
[1/1, ??:??/??:??] update: texlive.infra [223k] (54630 -> 57132) ... tlmgr: Restoring old package state succeeded.
done
tlmgr: The file README has disappeared from the critical package texlive.infra but is still present in dehyph:texmf-dist/tex/generic/dehyph/README dvipdfmx:texmf-dist/fonts/cmap/dvipdfmx/README koma-script:texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/README mfware:texmf-dist/mft/base/README texlive-msg-translations:tlpkg/translations/README texlive-scripts:texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvips/tetex/README
tlmgr: action update returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: package log updated: /usr/local/texlive/2020basic/texmf-var/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

This worked without any problems and without any error messages on macOS Catalina so most likely it has something to do with macOS Big Sur. How could I fix this and update `tlmgr`?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please install TeX Live Utility (you can get the latest beta from <[github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases](https://github.com/amaxwell/tlutility/releases)>) and run its Actions-> Renstall Tex Live Manager mwenu item. It does this via a new installer rather than through tlmgr itself.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem. And the error lies here "TLPDB::_install_package: unsupported container format xz".

Program "xz" is required to decompress the package. Use "brew install xz" if you use homebrew.

Comment: I solved the problem by running the following commands:  
    `$ brew install xz`
    `$ sudo tlmgr update --self` @naphaneal